# Clojure insert data to db

Tags: database, postgresql, clojure, lisp

i started learning clojure, and i have one problem.
I just have 2 files, project.clj

```
(defproject test-clojure-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A simple Clojure web project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [ring "1.10.0"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.10.0"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.5.0"]
                 [cheshire "5.10.0"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "42.3.1"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.11"]
                ;;  [ring/ring-reload "0.3.1"]
                 ]
  :main ^:skip-aot test-clojure-project.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

and src/test-clojure-project/core.clj`

```
(ns test-clojure-project.core
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [ring.util.response :as response]
            [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]]
            [cheshire.core :as json]
            [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [clojure.java.jdbc.ddl :as ddl]))

(def db-spec
  {:subprotocol "postgresql"
   :subname "//localhost/test_db"
   :user "postgres"
   :password "secret"})

(def posts-table
  [:posts
   [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
   [:content :text]])

(defn create-post [post]
  (jdbc/with-connection db-spec
    (jdbc/insert! :posts
                  {:content (:content post)})))

(defn get-data []
  (jdbc/with-connection db-spec
    (jdbc/query "SELECT * FROM posts")))

(defn handler [request]
  (let [uri (:uri request)]
    (cond
      (= uri "/posts-list")
      (let [response-data (get-data)]
        (response/response (str response-data)))

      (= uri "/create-post")
      (if (= (:request-method request) :post)
        (let [json-data (-> request :body slurp)
              parsed-data (json/parse-string json-data true)
              created-post (create-post parsed-data)]
          (response/response (json/generate-string created-post)))
        (response/response "Invalid request method"))

      :else
      (response/response "Route not found"))))

(defn -main []
  (do
    (println "Server started successfully on port 3000")
    ;; Create the 'posts' table if it doesn't exist
    (jdbc/with-connection db-spec
      (ddl/create-table-ddl posts-table :if-not-exists))
    (jetty/run-jetty (wrap-reload handler) {:port 3000})))
```

Am getting this error

```
2023-08-05 17:41:30.332:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1359ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
Exception in thread "main" Syntax error compiling at (test_clojure_project/core.clj:1:1).
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/java/jdbc/ddl__init.class, clojure/java/jdbc/ddl.clj or clojure/java/jdbc/ddl.cljc on classpath.
```

how can i fix it can somone help.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems affecting ns loading:

1. Clojure uses [munge](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/munge) to remove special characters from identifiers, like namespace names before looking up the corresponding resource. For example `-` is replaced by `_`.

Therefore, your source file should be in a folder named `test_clojure_project` instead.

2. There is no `clojure.java.jdbc.ddl` namespace defined in org.clojure/java.jdbc. Remove the `require` form and use just `jdbc/create-table-ddl`.

Comment: yes i renamed folder and removed clojure.java.jdbc.ddl from project.clj 
in core.clj i didnt change aniything, now am getting this error
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: jdbc

Comment: I looked through the history of clojure.java.jdbc -- the clojure.java.jdbc.ddl namespace existed very briefly: it was introduced in 0.3.0-alpha5 and removed in 0.3.0-beta2. So the code in the tutorial/book appears to be using a very short-lived prerelease (alpha5 or beta1)!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here. As Erdos pointed out, `clojure.java.jdbc.ddl` doesn't exist -- `create-table-ddl` is part of `clojure.java.jdbc`. And, yes, your file should be `src/test_clojure_project/core.clj` for a `ns` value of `test-clojure-project.core`.

You should remove `[clojure.java.jdbc.ddl :as ddl]` (but you still need `[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]` since you are using functions from that).

In addition, the code you have looks like it needs a much older version of `org.clojure/java.jdbc` -- in version 0.7.11 there is no `with-connection` and functions like `insert!` must be passed a db-spec as their first argument.

See https://cljdoc.org/d/org.clojure/java.jdbc/0.7.11/api/clojure.java.jdbc#insert! for the 0.7.11 docs (and note that it is not the most recent version).

Whatever tutorial or book you are learning from is outdated. Did you try using the exact versions for dependencies in `project.clj` that the tutorial/book said to use?

Answer (score 0):

I have a demo project using both the H2 and Postgres databases.

https://github.com/io-tupelo-demo/demo-jdbc-next

Just clone the project and run as follows:

```
~/io-tupelo-demo/demo-jdbc-next > ./pg-start.bash 
977fedce73349c6717033cf1025be4bf8a3d2e6893908579726902f126537e5c
~/io-tupelo-demo/demo-jdbc-next > lct
 => time (lein do clean, test)
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.

lein test _bootstrap

-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.11.1    Java 20.0.1
-----------------------------------

lein test tst.demo.jdbc-h2

lein test tst.demo.jdbc-postgres

Ran 7 tests containing 42 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
  35.53s user 0.86s system 326% cpu 11.156 total
~/io-tupelo-demo/demo-jdbc-next > 
~/io-tupelo-demo/demo-jdbc-next > 
~/io-tupelo-demo/demo-jdbc-next > ./pg-stop.bash 
pg-docker
```

It runs Postgres in a Docker container, so it assumes you have Docker installed.  If you don't want to use Docker/Postgres, you can go to the namespace `tst.demo.jdbc-postgres` ane make line 10 look like:

```
(def postgres-enable false)
```

which will disable Postgres and just run the H2 unit tests (pure java; uses only JAR files from Maven so no other install required).  Skip the `pg-start.bash` & `pg-stop.bash` files in this case.

Since you seem to already have Postgres installed, just update the username/password in the namespace `tst.demo.jdbc-postgres`